# Unusual notation for integer, rational and real numbers (A. J. Moakes M.A., The Core of Mathematics)

Tags: reference-request, notation

I am reading currently an old book: A. J. Moakes M.A., The Core of Mathematics, An introduction to 'modern' mathematics (1964). The author uses some unusual (at least to me) notation for integer, rational and real numbers alike:

[image]

Are there other authors that use such a notation? Is just an 'anomaly' of the author's book?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I *think* Rudin used the notation $J$ for the integers in "baby Rudin." Using the notation $R$ for the rationals, and $R^\#$ for the reals did not age well...

Comment: @AlexOrtiz  yes,  so far he is using $J$  for the positive integers. I posted as  answer

Comment: The usage of Q and Z for rational numbers and integers is usually thought to have started with Bourbaki. In the 60s that french wave may have not have reached the US?

Comment: Birkhoff and maclane's *Survey of Modern Algebra*, from the early 50s and which probably had as much influence on notation choices as on everything else in the US, uses J for the integers

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  there's no hiding it, we are backwards.

Comment: Well, had it been Ⴑ then we would go as far as that :-)

Comment: You are wise. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

page 25 in the third edition of baby Rudin.   Earlier he says properties of the integers will be assumed; from what I can see, he uses integers mostly  as an indexing set for sequences or series, so positive integers. I'll try to find a later page that uses $J$

[image]
[image]